# Maven dependency conflicts

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to resolve dependency version conflicts while using the below dependencies.

The worst one I am facing is `zucchini` project supports the apache `commons-io` versions from 1.4 to latest one. It does not support versions
below 1.4
and at the same time `pagerduty-client` supports `commons-io` versions below 1.4 version.
So It is not possible to specify a common version of this dependency (dependency management)
which supports in both zucchini and pager-duty client (both are third party libraries).

[image]

In this particular situation I couldn't find a possible way to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.comcast.zucchini</groupId>
            <artifactId>zucchini</artifactId>
            <version>[2.2.5,)</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dikhan</groupId>
            <artifactId>pagerduty-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe this can be "solved" with the Maven shade plugin.

Comment: First I would recommend to remove the version range you are using afterwards I would suggest to add an explicit dependency to commons-io version 1.4 to start with. If you unit tests will succeed you can change it...

Comment: Is there an actual problem with the differing versions? Or do you just not like the fact that the versions don't align?

Comment: the first one-problem with different versions.zucchini and pagerduty must use different versions of commons-io.

Comment: So is there a compilation error or something?

Comment: I tried to choose a common version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io that works compatible with both zucchini and pagerduty...but i couldn't

Comment: That's the problem with some versions of jakarta commons. Sometimes the only thing you can do is downgrade something in order to get it to use the older commons version when no newer version of the conflicting library is available.

Comment: @paul zucchini API in my project supports to generate some reports...it will not work if i use io versions below 1.4...also pager duty is using to send some failures to pagerduty platform...pagerduty client only works with commons-io versions 1.3.2 and below vesions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibility 1**

If the old and new commons-io package/class names are a close enough match, excluding the old dependency from `pagerduty-client` could possibly work.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dikhan</groupId>
        <artifactId>pagerduty-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

This relies on the binary API of commons-io between versions 1.3.2 and 2.x being similar enough.

There does seem to be lots of overlap, looking at the code of each version:

- https://github.com/apache/commons-io/tree/commons-io-1.3.2/src/java/org/apache/commons/io
- https://github.com/apache/commons-io/tree/commons-io-2.5/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io

**Possibility 2**

Split up your application so that the commons-io dependency is not shared and does not conflict.

It could be that the `pagerduty-client` and `zucchini` parts of your application do not need to be 'bundled' together, so split them up.

If they *do* need work together then you could still have two apps/processes and send messages between them.

**Note**

I cloned the `pagerduty-client` [repo](https://github.com/dikhan/pagerduty-client) and changed the commons-io dependency from `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2` to `commons-io:commons-io:2.5` and the tests worked, so maybe you can suggest to the project owner that they upgrade commons-io.

And looking at the code it seems commons-io is hardly used (one place, `HttpApiServiceImpl.java`):

```
\pagerduty-client>findstr /s /c:"commons" *.java
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\domain\AcknowledgeIncident.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\domain\Incident.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\domain\Incident.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.Builder;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\domain\Payload.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\domain\ResolveIncident.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\HttpApiServiceImpl.java:import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\PagerDutyEventsClient.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
src\main\java\com\github\dikhan\pagerduty\client\events\utils\FakePagerDutyEventsClient.java:import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Answer (score 1):

As your commons-io is the problem you'll have to look further up the line. That means either upgrade pagerduty-client to a version that uses a newer version of commons-io that Cucumber likes, or downgrade zucchini to require a version of Cucumber that works with pagerduty-client as well.

This is a common problem with some jakarta commons packages, they at some point decided to massively change the public interface without changing the package name, causing conflicts like this for users.

You may be in luck, I once worked on a project where we had to rewrite thousands of lines of code just so we could link to a library we desperately needed that depended on a newer version of commons-io than the one we'd been using.